# How to merge two matrix into one matrix respectively based on the columns number Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, merge

Example I have

```
A =[1 2;
    3 4]

B =[5 6;
    7 8]
```

I want the result is like this

```
C =[1 5 2 6;
    3 7 4 8]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "Give me the code" request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate vertically and then `reshape` -

```
C = reshape([A;B],size(A,1),[])
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2
     3     4
>> B
B =
     5     6
     7     8
>> reshape([A;B],size(A,1),[])
ans =
     1     5     2     6
     3     7     4     8
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the use, but with this particular example, you can make it like this:

```
C= [A, B];
```

and then:

```
C1=[C(:,1),C(:,3),C(:,2),C(:,4)]

C1 =

     1     5     2     6
     3     7     4     8
```